# How to activate system idle state of Windows?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, screensaver

I am working on a C application which runs in the background without any Windows control.

I want to put Windows in a system idle state as if the screen saver is enabled and the ScreenSaveTimeOut value is reached.

I can simulate the desired behaviour to some extent by using SystemParametersInfo with SPI_SETSCREENSAVERACTIVE and SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT=1 parameters.

Unfortunately, this requires me to use a screen saver.

Are there any APIs available which I could use in order to put Windows directly in an idle state?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't really put the system into an idle state manually, only user activity manages that. But, you can invoke the user's screensaver by sending a [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360.aspx)(`SC_SCREENSAVE`) message to the foreground window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`SetSuspendState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373201(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`SetSystemPowerState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373206(v=vs.85).aspx) are what you are looking for.